# Comparing python -V output for Python version checking in bash

Tags: python, bash

I am creating an install script where I would like to compare the version of installed default Python with the version I need to have running. Currently here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON="$(python -V)"
if [[ "$PYTHON = 'Python 2.7.6' ]]
then echo "Python is installed."
else echo "Python is not installed."
fi
```

The response I keep getting is that Python is not installed, but that is the output when I type in the command python -V.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: think it would be, `if [[ "$PYTHON" == 'Python 2.7.6' ]]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I thought that correcting the `if` would solve the case, but it actually didn't: `python -V` prints the version just fine but it returns an empty result. So the variable is always empty.

Comment: you want to check the existence of python or this particular version of python?

Comment: This particular version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when you run `python -V`, it prints the version to *stderr*, not to stdout. So, changing your attempt to capture the output into a variable to this:

```
PYTHON=$(python -V 2>&1)
```

should do the trick. Another alternative, which tends to include additional information about build dates, compilers, etc. would be:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.version'
```

or, as suggested by @chepner:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.version_info'
```

Both of these would require a little additional parsing to get the specific information you want/need, though.

Comment: `sys.version_info` would be better, since you can access various components of the version number in a  controlled way.

Comment: The first answer you gave achieved exactly what was needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON="$(python -V 2>&1)"
if [[ "$PYTHON" = "Python 2.7.6" ]]; then
    echo "Python is installed."
else
    echo "Python is not installed."
fi
```

Comment: While this lets me know that Python is installed, I need to know the specific version installed. I am creating the script to automate the installation process of Jekyll for Windows users and Python 2.7.* works where Python 3.* does not.

Comment: @Jahid your explanation of `exit` and what gets fed to the `bash` "capture standard output and assign it to a variable" construct (i.e. `$(...)`) is incorrect.

Comment: don't use `which` to check command existence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: Can you explain a little, @twalberg

Comment: @twalberg, Due to having doubt about my theory I removed that portion, but still I need an explanation, if you may...

Comment: @Jahid `PYTHON=$(...)` captures the standard output of a program, which, by token of the fact that `${PYTHON}` was ending up empty, demonstrates the fact that `python -V` in fact produces no output on standard output (it goes to standard error, instead). The exit library call returns an exit code to the shell, which is a different concept than writing something to the output. This is somewhat confused by the fact that Python provides an overloaded `exit()` call such that `exit('foo')` is roughly equivalent to `print 'foo'; exit()`...